# SQL Server - How can I optimize my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT CO.*
FROM CORPORATION CO
LEFT JOIN CORPORATION SU
ON CO.CORP_NAME = SU.PARENT_CORP_NAME
WHERE CO.PARENT_CORP_NAME IN
    (SELECT CO.CORP_NAME
     FROM CORPORATION CO
     INNER JOIN BANK B ON B.CORP_NAME = CO.CORP_NAME AND B.COUNTRY_NAME=CO.COUNTRY_NAME
     INNER JOIN COUNTRY C ON CO.BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY=C.COUNTRY_NAME
     WHERE C.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1
     UNION
     SELECT CO.CORP_NAME
     FROM CORPORATION CO
     INNER JOIN COUNTRY C ON CO.COUNTRY_NAME = C.COUNTRY_NAME
     WHERE C.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1)
OR SU.CORP_NAME IN
    (SELECT CO.CORP_NAME
     FROM CORPORATION CO
     INNER JOIN BANK B ON B.CORP_NAME = CO.CORP_NAME AND B.COUNTRY_NAME=CO.COUNTRY_NAME
     INNER JOIN COUNTRY C ON CO.BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY=C.COUNTRY_NAME
     WHERE C.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1
     UNION
     SELECT CO.CORP_NAME
     FROM CORPORATION CO
     INNER JOIN COUNTRY C ON CO.COUNTRY_NAME = C.COUNTRY_NAME
     WHERE C.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1)
```

It feels like a very unefficient way to get the data I want. Is there a way to reduce this query to a more efficient version?

The table CORPORATION has the following columns:

- COUNTRY_NAME
- CORP_NAME
- PARENT_COUNTRY_NAME
- PARENT_CORP_NAME
- BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the `UNION` in your `WHERE` clause? It looks a bit redundant, but I'm guessing there's a reason you've unioned that data?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the query does.

Comment: Learn this. When you refer to a column from the unpreserved table in an outer join in the where clause, that forces the outer join to an inner join. And using union requires sorting to eliminate duplicates. This is not needed in the subquery used with IN - you gain a bit of performance by replacing UNION with UNION ALL.

Comment: Why are you joining to `Bank`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your joins, this is a shot in the dark. Seems like you can get rid of the `UNION` by using an OR operator in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT CO.*
FROM CORPORATION CO
LEFT JOIN CORPORATION SU ON CO.CORP_NAME = SU.PARENT_CORP_NAME
WHERE CO.PARENT_CORP_NAME IN
    (SELECT CO.CORP_NAME
     FROM CORPORATION CO
     INNER JOIN BANK B ON B.CORP_NAME = CO.CORP_NAME 
        AND (B.COUNTRY_NAME=CO.COUNTRY_NAME OR CO.COUNTRY_NAME = C.COUNTRY_NAME)
     INNER JOIN COUNTRY C ON CO.BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY=C.COUNTRY_NAME
     WHERE C.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1)
OR SU.CORP_NAME IN
    (SELECT CO.CORP_NAME
     FROM CORPORATION CO
     INNER JOIN BANK B ON B.CORP_NAME = CO.CORP_NAME 
        AND (B.COUNTRY_NAME=CO.COUNTRY_NAME OR CO.COUNTRY_NAME = C.COUNTRY_NAME)
     INNER JOIN COUNTRY C ON CO.BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY=C.COUNTRY_NAME
     WHERE C.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UNION`s in the subqueries are going to kill performance.  So you can start with:

```
WHERE CO.PARENT_CORP_NAME IN
    (SELECT CO.CORP_NAME
     FROM CORPORATION CO JOIN
          BANK B
          ON B.CORP_NAME = CO.CORP_NAME AND
             B.COUNTRY_NAME = CO.COUNTRY_NAME JOIN
          COUNTRY C
          ON CO.BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY=C.COUNTRY_NAME
     WHERE C.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1
    ) OR
     CO.PARENT_CORP_NAME IN
   (SELECT CO.CORP_NAME
    FROM CORPORATION CO JOIN
         COUNTRY C
         ON CO.COUNTRY_NAME = C.COUNTRY_NAME
     WHERE C.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1
    ) OR
    . . .
```

That should help.  But it might optimize better with `EXISTS` rather than `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
with corp_name_cte(corp_name) as (
    select co.corp_name
    from corporation co
         join bank b on b.corp_name = co.corp_name 
                        and b.country_name=co.country_name
         join country c on co.banking_license_country=c.country_name
     where c.is_tax_haven = 1
     union
     select co.corp_name
     from corporation co
          join country c on co.country_name = c.country_name
     where c.is_tax_haven = 1)
select co.*, su.parent_corp_name
from corporation co
     join corp_name_cte cn on co.corp_name=cn.corp_name
     left join corporation su on co.corp_name = su.parent_corp_name
     left join corp_name_cte sucn on su.corp_name=sucn.corp_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

With just plain joins, and assuming that BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY is only filled when needed amd is applicable when filled:

```
SELECT CO.*
FROM CORPORATION CO
INNER JOIN COUNTRY C_CO ON C_CO.COUNTRY_NAME = CO.COUNTRY_NAME
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY C_B_CO ON C_B_CO.BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY=CO.COUNTRY_NAME
    
LEFT JOIN CORPORATION SU ON CO.CORP_NAME = SU.PARENT_CORP_NAME
INNER JOIN COUNTRY C_SU ON C_SU.COUNTRY_NAME = SU.COUNTRY_NAME
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY C_B_SU ON C_B_SU.BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY=SU.COUNTRY_NAME
    
WHERE (C_CO.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1 OR C_B_CO.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1) 
OR (C_SU.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1 OR C_B_SU.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1)
```

If it is important wether or not there is actually an existing BANK record, which might be the reason why you would need the join to BANK, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT CO.*
FROM CORPORATION CO
INNER JOIN COUNTRY C_CO ON C_CO.COUNTRY_NAME = CO.COUNTRY_NAME
LEFT JOIN BANK B_CO ON B_CO.CORP_NAME = CO.CORP_NAME AND B_SU.COUNTRY_NAME=CO.COUNTRY_NAME
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY C_B_CO ON C_B_CO.BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY=CO.COUNTRY_NAME AND B_CO.ID IS NOT NULL

LEFT JOIN CORPORATION SU ON CO.CORP_NAME = SU.PARENT_CORP_NAME
INNER JOIN COUNTRY C_SU ON C_SU.COUNTRY_NAME = SU.COUNTRY_NAME
LEFT JOIN BANK B_SU ON B_SU.CORP_NAME = SU.CORP_NAME AND B_SU.COUNTRY_NAME=SU.COUNTRY_NAME
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY C_B_SU ON C_B_SU.BANKING_LICENSE_COUNTRY=SU.COUNTRY_NAME AND B_SU.ID IS NOT NULL

WHERE (C_CO.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1 OR C_B_CO.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1) 
AND (C_SU.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1 OR C_B_SU.IS_TAX_HAVEN = 1)
```